# Calling CodeBehind Method Exposed as a WebMethod via AJAX triggering Page_Init and Page_Load

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

So I have the following jQuery AJAX:

```
   $.ajax({
                url: 'Esign.aspx/LoadPdf',
                data: {
                    withEsign:'<%= WithEsign%>',
                    isPreview:'<%= IsPreview%>'
                },
                cache: false,
                context: document.body,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
```

Then in my code behind I have:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string LoadPdf(bool withEsign = false, bool isPreview = true)
    {
        return url;
    }
```

The problem is that my Page_Init and Page_Load are being triggered and **IsPostPack is false**

Comment: I'm really shocked by that; I thought they would never run for page methods approach.  There may be a property you can check to see that when true, it will disable that.  Check the IsCallback Or there are a few other Is<X> properties that may be beneficial.

Comment: I ended up exposing the method I was trying to call in a generic handler instead. Had to pass some extra variables that I already had in the code behind but no big deal.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify the data parameter before sending it.